# Change order of layers in Flash MovieClip with ActionScript?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

Is it possible to change the order of layers in a Flash MovieClip timeline using ActionScript 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the layer order, but you can change the z-index (stacking order) of a movie clip within a same layer. So you can consolidate all the relevant movie clips into one layer, then change the z index using acrtionscript.

```
parent.setChildIndex(childObject, i)
```

Change childObject to the name of the movie clip you want to change the z-index, change i to an integer (the desired z-index value).

If you want to make this happen on a mouse event, put above code inside a function and attach an event listener to a button to invoke this function on a mouse event.

Comment: Correct- and to clarify, this is because "As far as flash is concerned once the movie is published , you can imagine everything as being on ONE single layer, with things at varying depths according to the layer they where on at author time" -http://board.flashkit.com/board/showpost.php?p=3603262&postcount=2